# Resize a hidden Modal Popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, resize, bootstrap-modal

I have a hidden Modal popup that is declared in the HTML in the following way:

```html
<div id="rbe_popupContainer" class="modal hide ui-resizable ui-draggable" style="overflow: hidden; position: fixed; display: none; width: 700px; height: 400px; margin-left: -350px; margin-top: -200px; left: 50%; top: 50%;" aria-hidden="true">
  <div id="rbe_popupContainerHeader">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button id="rbe_popCloseBox" type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" style="display: block;">×</button> <span style="display: block; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap; line-height: 1.4em;" id="rbe_popupTitle" class="large bold" title="Attach">Attach</span> 
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body" id="rbe_popupIframeContainer" style="padding: 0px; overflow-x: hidden; height: 361px; width: 700px;">
    <iframe src="../xyz.jsp?act=clean&amp;pageId=16238&amp;funcName=create23080" class="full-iframe" style="height: 361px; display: block; width: 700px; background-color: transparent;" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" id="rbe_popupFrame"
    name="rbe_popupFrame"></iframe>
    <div id="maskDiv" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:100%;display:none">
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e"></div>
  <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s"></div>
  <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 1001;"></div>
</div>
```

And I would like to change the Modal popup size i.e. width and height when a user clicks on a button to open this modal using jQuery. I've tried using:

```
$("#rbe_popupContainer").on("show.bs.modal", function() {
      var height = $(window).height() - 200;
      alert(height);
      $(this).find(".modal-body").css("max-height", height);
    });
```

But it doesn't seem to work. What is the best way to resize this modal popup window? Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you able to isolate this code into a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) please? At first glance it appears your sytnax for the function isn't correct. You're passing in a selector into the .on method when actually you should be passing in an option such as "click".

Comment: This is just the modal code which is hidden from the user. When a user clicks on a button that is lets say have an id="myButton", then the above modal is shown and the user can interact with. I would just like to resize this modal popup.

Answer (score 0):

Your example should work, I guess the only mistake is that you need to add `+ 'px'` to `'max-height':height+ 'px'`.

Therefore change your jQuery to this:

```
$("#rbe_popupContainer").on("show.bs.modal", function() {
    var height = $(window).height() - 200;
    alert(height);
    $(this).find(".modal-body").css("max-height", height + 'px');
});
```

I created a simple example [**here**](http://www.bootply.com/GMIVHdHIDT).

Comment: Not sure why but the alert doesn't fire i.e. when the modal is shown the above jquery doesn't run.

Comment: I think it should be modal-dialog in your bootply example.

Comment: does the console say anything?

Comment: Nope it doesn't say anything.